# Output gives nothing

Tags: java, arraylist

class A contain:

```
public static ArrayList<String> sourceList = new ArrayList<String>();
// here ArrayList contain some string type data; 
public static ArrayList<String> getSource()
    {
        return sourceList;
    }
```

main class contain:

```
List<String> s1 = A.getSource();
for(String dk:s1) {
            System.out.println(dk);
        }
```

Here I am storing ArrayList data of class A into a list in class B and checking
whether its works or not.but when I run the main class it gives nothing.

thanks.

Comment: if list contain data it will print in the output.but its not happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've simulated what you are doing, and it's working as expected. Are you sure the list is being populated correctly?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class PrintList {


    public static void main(String[] args) {


        List<String> s1 = AClass.getSource();

        for (String dk : s1) {
            System.out.println("We have : " + dk);
        }
    }
}

class AClass {
    public static final ArrayList<String> sourceList = new ArrayList<String>();

    static {
        sourceList.add("A string");
        sourceList.add("Another string");        
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> getSource() {
        return sourceList;
    }
}
```

Comment: is import java.util.ArrayList; is necessary coz it gives never used warning

Comment: In which class?  You need to have that line in any class which uses the word `ArrayList`.

Comment: Correct - you only need it in the class that contains the actual ArrayList called sourceList.

Answer (score 0):

If that is all the code you are using, then you will never get anything since you are never populating the array list in the first place.

If you really want to see if it is working, try something like so:

```
public static ArrayList<String> sourceList = new ArrayList<String>();
// here ArrayList contain some string type data; 
public static ArrayList<String> getSource()
{
    sourceList.add("Hello I am working");
    return sourceList;
}
```

If all goes well, you should see the string `Hello I am working`.

Comment: I already populate the sourceList but I can't show the code here

Comment: @user1370786: Then there isn't much we can do unfortunately.